# Swatch Thumbnail in Minibag

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

When selecting a swatch and adding an item to the bag the master product image is shown in the minibag. We would like the image of the selected swatch to be the thumbnail. Is there a script to do this?

Magento 2.1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Magento out of box functionality. You can chagen this from below configuration setting from admin panel

```
Store => Configurations => Sales => Checkout => Shopping cart => Configurable product image
```

Select: Product Thumbnail Itself

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Kul That worked perfectly

Comment: Glad to know that @DaveLynch